# How can I move the images or the text within the column of a row such that it does not lose it's responsiveness?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

How can i move the images to the end of the column?

I have used the float:right as well as the margin-left but after using it the columns lose their responsiveness as increase or decrease the window of my browser.

How can i move the images to the left

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foundation.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 column">
    Login Register Contact Us
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 large-6 medium-6 column">
    <img src="facebook.ico" height="35px" width="35px">
    <img src="google+.ico" height="35px" width="35px">
    <img src="instagram.ico" height="35px" width="35px">
    <img src="twitter.ico" height="35px" width="35px">
    <img src="youtube.ico" height="35px" width="35px">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be more specific, as giving a screenshot of what's happening ?

I tested it in a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/m3xvsL1v/

I just added a wrapper `<div class="right"><img .../><img ... /></div>` to make them align to right.

I couldn't reproduce any size increasing or decreazing of the column.

Hope this helps,